# How can you instantiate an Interface?

Tags: java, swing, interface, awt, actionlistener

In Swing I'm using `ActionListener` or any other Listener interface.

In general I can't create object of Interface.
If I use new operator with any constructor name a object is created.

I have a problem with my code below:

> jbtOK : is some button object
>
> ActionListener is an interface.

How can I use new `ActionListener()` in `addActionListener` method?

Since an object is created. but, I can't create a object from an interface.

Is it only possible in inner classes? i.e, in inner classes I can create objects of interface:

```
jbtOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           
         System.out.println("hi");
       }
     });
```

Comment: this is a question, without any research

Comment: This is not a bad question. It is just badly formulated. sri asks "How can you instantiate an Interface? We have learned that Interfaces are not Classes!"

Comment: Good question for beginners, everyone has a first time! However, it's a good practice research before ask here...

Answer (score 3):

with the **new** keyword you create the object into the memory and as you create the object object of an interface it's need to be implement. lets compare with the explicit class

suppose you define the class which implement this ActionListener interface what you do?

```
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener{
    // now here you need implement all of the method which defined into the ActionListener interface
}
```

now you can use this class to register listener for Action like this way

```
jbtOK.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
```

this was the explicit implement and as you directly implement it's called Anonymous class as you defined here with ActionListener interface

Comment: Yes, I think he has forgotten the `implements ActionListener` words.

Answer (score 1):

http://mindprod.com/jgloss/interface.html#INSTANTIATING:

You can’t instantiate an interface directly, but you can instantiate a class that implements an interface. References to an Object can by via the class name, via one of its superclass names, or one of its interface names.

Read also a few things about anonymous classes.

```
new class-name ( [ argument-list ] ) { class-body }
```

It is an **anonymous class** you are instantiating and passing to your addActionListener method. addActionListener takes an ActionListener as an argument, so since you provide an actionPerformed method it assumes that the anonymous class you pass to it is an ActionListener.

Try to change the name of this actionPerformed method. It will not work anymore since the anonymous class you are passing does not implement the ActionListener Interface. See the error message you get by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you cannot use the methods of an interface, because an interface has all its methods as abstract (empty, without implementation), then you have to implement all the methods requested by your interface.

For example, because you have to add an `ActionListener` to a button, then associate it to action called in `actionPerformed` method, you have to declare in the first lines of your code:

```
public class your_class implements ActionListener
```

Where the keyword `implements` is needed to indicate you are implementing the abstract methods of the `ActionListener` interface, or any other interface, to use these methods with your objects.